# How to listen for the right ACK message from Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am doing a *POC* with Spring Boot & Kafka for a transactional project and I have the following doubt:

**Scenario:**
One microservices *MSPUB1* receives Requests from the customer. That requests publish a message on topic *TRANSACTION_TOPIC1* on Kafka but that Microservice could receive multiple requests in parallel. The Microservice listens the topic *TRANSACTION_RESULT1* to check that the transaction finished.

In the other side of the Streaming Platform, another Microservice *MSSUB1* is listening the topic *TRANSACTION_TOPIC1* and process all messages and publish the results on: *TRANSACTION_RESULT1*

What is the best way from *MSPUB1* to know if the message on topic *TRANSACTION_RESULT1* matches with his original request? The microservice *MSPUB1* could have a ID for any message published on the initial topic *TRANSACTION_TOPIC1* and be moved to *TRANSACTION_RESULT1*

**Question:**
When you are reading the partition, you move the pointer but in a concurrency environment with multiple requests, how to check if the message on the topic *TRANSACTION_RESULT1* is the expected?

Many thanks in advance

Juan Antonio

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use a [Spring Integration `BarrierMessageHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-routing.html#barrier).

Here is an example app. Hopefully, it's self-explanatory. Kafka 0.11 or higher is needed...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class So48349993Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So48349993Application.class);

    private static final String TRANSACTION_TOPIC1 = "TRANSACTION_TOPIC1";

    private static final String TRANSACTION_RESULT1 = "TRANSACTION_RESULT1";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48349993Application.class, args);
    }

    private final Exchanger exchanger;

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public So48349993Application(Exchanger exchanger,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.exchanger = exchanger;
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
        kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic(TRANSACTION_RESULT1);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/foo/{id}/{other}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String foo(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String other) {
        logger.info("Controller received: " + other);
        String reply = this.exchanger.exchange(id, other);
        // if reply is null, we timed out
        logger.info("Controller replying: " + reply);
        return reply;
    }

    // Client side

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "outbound", defaultReplyTimeout = "10000")
    public interface Exchanger {

        @Gateway
        String exchange(@Header(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID) String id,
                @Payload String out);

    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow router() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("outbound")
                .routeToRecipients(r -> r
                        .recipient("toKafka")
                        .recipient("barrierChannel"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outFlow(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("toKafka")
                .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).topic(TRANSACTION_TOPIC1))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow barrierFlow(BarrierMessageHandler barrier) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("barrierChannel")
                .handle(barrier)
                .transform("payload.get(1)") // payload is list with input/reply
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public BarrierMessageHandler barrier() {
        return new BarrierMessageHandler(10_000L);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "clientReply", topics = TRANSACTION_RESULT1)
    public void result(Message<?> reply) {
        logger.info("Received reply: " + reply.getPayload() + " for id "
                + reply.getHeaders().get(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID));
        barrier().trigger(reply);
    }

    // Server side

    @KafkaListener(id = "server", topics = TRANSACTION_TOPIC1)
    public void service(String in,
            @Header(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID) String id) throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Service Received " + in);
        Thread.sleep(5_000);
        logger.info("Service Replying to " + in);
        // with spring-kafka 2.0 (and Boot 2), you can return a String and use @SendTo instead of this.
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(new GenericMessage<>("reply for " + in,
                Collections.singletonMap(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID, id)));
    }

    // Provision topics if needed

    // provided by Boot in 2.0
    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin admin() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        return new KafkaAdmin(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return new NewTopic(TRANSACTION_TOPIC1, 10, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic result1() {
        return new NewTopic(TRANSACTION_RESULT1, 10, (short) 1);
    }

}
```

Result

```
2018-01-20 17:27:54.668  INFO 98522 --- [   server-1-C-1] com.example.So48349993Application        : Service Received foo
2018-01-20 17:27:55.782  INFO 98522 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.example.So48349993Application        : Controller received: bar
2018-01-20 17:27:55.788  INFO 98522 --- [   server-0-C-1] com.example.So48349993Application        : Service Received bar
2018-01-20 17:27:59.673  INFO 98522 --- [   server-1-C-1] com.example.So48349993Application        : Service Replying to foo
2018-01-20 17:27:59.702  INFO 98522 --- [ientReply-1-C-1] com.example.So48349993Application        : Received reply: reply for foo for id 1
2018-01-20 17:27:59.705  INFO 98522 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.So48349993Application        : Controller replying: reply for foo
2018-01-20 17:28:00.792  INFO 98522 --- [   server-0-C-1] com.example.So48349993Application        : Service Replying to bar
2018-01-20 17:28:00.798  INFO 98522 --- [ientReply-0-C-1] com.example.So48349993Application        : Received reply: reply for bar for id 2
2018-01-20 17:28:00.800  INFO 98522 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.example.So48349993Application        : Controller replying: reply for bar
```

Pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>so48349993</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>so48349993</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency=2
```

**EDIT**

And here is a version that uses Spring Integration on the server side, instead of `@KafkaListener`...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class So483499931Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So483499931Application.class);

    private static final String TRANSACTION_TOPIC1 = "TRANSACTION_TOPIC3";

    private static final String TRANSACTION_RESULT1 = "TRANSACTION_RESULT3";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So483499931Application.class, args);
    }

    private final Exchanger exchanger;

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public So483499931Application(Exchanger exchanger,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.exchanger = exchanger;
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
        kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic(TRANSACTION_RESULT1);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/foo/{id}/{other}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String foo(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String other) {
        logger.info("Controller received: " + other);
        String reply = this.exchanger.exchange(id, other);
        logger.info("Controller replying: " + reply);
        return reply;
    }

    // Client side

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "outbound", defaultReplyTimeout = "10000")
    public interface Exchanger {

        @Gateway
        String exchange(@Header(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID) String id,
                @Payload String out);

    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow router() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("outbound")
                .routeToRecipients(r -> r
                        .recipient("toKafka")
                        .recipient("barrierChannel"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outFlow(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("toKafka")
                .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).topic(TRANSACTION_TOPIC1))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow barrierFlow(BarrierMessageHandler barrier) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("barrierChannel")
                .handle(barrier)
                .transform("payload.get(1)") // payload is list with input/reply
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public BarrierMessageHandler barrier() {
        return new BarrierMessageHandler(10_000L);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "clientReply", topics = TRANSACTION_RESULT1)
    public void result(Message<?> reply) {
        logger.info("Received reply: " + reply.getPayload() + " for id "
                + reply.getHeaders().get(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID));
        barrier().trigger(reply);
    }

    // Server side

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow server(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(consumerFactory, TRANSACTION_TOPIC1))
            .handle("so483499931Application", "service")
            .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).topic(TRANSACTION_RESULT1))
            .get();
    }

    public String service(String in) throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Service Received " + in);
        Thread.sleep(5_000);
        logger.info("Service Replying to " + in);
        return "reply for " + in;
    }

    // Provision topics if needed

    // provided by Boot in 2.0
    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin admin() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        return new KafkaAdmin(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return new NewTopic(TRANSACTION_TOPIC1, 10, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic result1() {
        return new NewTopic(TRANSACTION_RESULT1, 10, (short) 1);
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency=2
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=server
```

Comment: Hi @Gary, I am going to test in local your example and I will send some questions about it. I appreciate so much your time. Give me some hours to review in detail the example. I will reply with my comments. Cheers

Comment: Hi Gary! Do you mind to explain this a little bit more please? `.transform("payload.get(1)") // payload is list with input/reply` Thanks

Comment: As the comment says; the default output processor in the `BarrierMessageHandler` returns a message with the payload being a list of the input + reply payloads. So the transformer transforms that message to just the reply. However, since this answer was added, Spring Integration now provides an outbound gateway which makes this use case simpler. https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/kafka.html#kafka-outbound-gateway Also an inbound gateway for the server side.

Comment: Hi Gary, if I got it right this solution works if the response is expected a short time after the request is sent and the calling application does not go down in the meantime. Is there a component inside the Spring framework to persist the correlation id between request and response and to execute some code when the response arrives?

Comment: No; but you can add a `discardChannel` to the barrier handler and late arriving responses will be sent there, where you can do with them whatever you please.